# Toggle DIV visibility based on Link click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains some alphabetical Information, for each starting letter several paragraphs. on top of that page I want to have the letters A-Z clickable, if I click on one of the letters only the div containing the paragraphs with the letter should be showed.

example:

```
A B C D

<div id=A>
Amsterdam
Ankara
</div>
<div id=B>
Brussel
Budapest
</div>
<div id=C>
Calgary
Cairo
</div>
```

I have found some samples, but having a script function for every letter, I just want one function identifying which letter was choosen, hides all divs A-Z and Shows the div for the clicked letter.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: So what HTML are you starting with, and what HTML do you want to end up with?

Comment: Can we at least see your HTML for the ABCD links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, thanks to all who responded in a productive way. THANK YOU.

second, this is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/RMra8/

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divSelect a').click(function (e) {

            var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
                $('#' + nextChar).fadeOut();
            }
            var txt = $(e.target).text();
            $('#' + txt).delay(400).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have a common class for your links (I'll use `letterLink`) as well as your divs (I'll use `letterDiv`).

```
$("a.letterLink").click(function() {
    $(".letterDiv").hide();
    var letter = $(this).text();
    $("#" + letter).show();
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to suggest after seeing his links. +1

Comment: If you don't want to constrain yourself to the text being the exact ID (for example, spaces would be invalid), you can add an extra attribute to the link (`<a divtarget="A">A</a>`) and use that with `.attr('divtarget')` instead of `.text()`. This will cause your page not to validate but it works. A better solution would be to use `<a href="#A">A</a>` but then you will need jQuery to store the `href` as `.data()` and replace it with something invalid so the page doesn't scroll when you click the links.

Comment: @meustrus, or just use data attributes (`data-divtarget="A"`) and then use jQuery's `.data()` in a perfectly valid, standards-complying way.

Comment: This binds an event for each letter and then has to search the DOM every time a letter is clicked. It would be better to cache the $('.letterDiv') and to bind the click event on a letter wrapper element.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. Each of the letters has to be a link, meaning you have to wrap each letter in  tags. You can do this with JavaScript or manually if you really want to.
2. Wrap your div id's in quotation "" marks to meet some standards.
3. Put a class on each div that is showable.
4. Put a class on each link (or wrap a div around the links with a specific class and use event delegation, see http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/
5. Use jQuery to attach a listener to the links class.

   1. Within the listeners, detect which letter has been clicked (different based on your approach to step 4.
   2. Hide all of the showable divs.
   3. Show the div whose id is the letter that has been clicked.

No code, all hints.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery this could be very easy :) just give all of the letter categories a specific class like class="category" and then use jQuery to hide them and given a passed object set it's display back to block.

```
$("a.categoryLink").click(function() {

    $(".category").hide();

    var letter = $(this).text();

    $("#" + letter").show();

});
```

Comment: Oh I was beaten to it!

Answer (score 0):

I have a mild obsession with data attributes, and so prefer this approach.

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <a href="#">B</a>
</div>
<div data-letter="A">
    Aadvark
    Apple
</div>
<div data-letter="B">
    Banana
    Bermuda
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".links a").click(function(){
    $("[data-letter]").hide();
    var letter = $(this).text();
    $("[data-letter="+letter+"]").show();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the data-letter attr be more appropriate in the links div? Then you know which content div to show by using the attr as the id.

Comment: I guess it depends. If you're coding for your own convenience, your suggested method means typing the letter three times: `data-letter="A"`, `A</a>` and `id="A"`. With mine, it's two (although you could get it down to one with some seriously OTT coding, such as reading the first character of the `div` XD)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to do it.

Put your letter links in a container.
    A B C D...

Add a class to your divs

```
<div id='A' class='content'>
```

Add a click event to the container instead of the letter (1 vs 26)

```
// cache the collection
var content_divs = $('.content');

$('#letters').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(content_divs).hide();      
  var letter = $(this).text();
  $('#' + letter).show();
});
```